# ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 display "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

Whenever i execute

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4
```

it return Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

I am attaching snapshot here

[image]

Comment: Can you play the file with `ffplay filename.mp4`?

Comment: looks like you're on an ancient version of ffmpeg possibly..2008?

Answer (score -1):

Well, not same use-case, but looks like `avconv` should be used instead. Incidentally, I haven't had much luck with `avconv` so far, but I suspect that's because I'm using a Raspberry Pi and there may be codec issues.

```
ffmpeg -i *-00.jpg -r 25 movie.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.8.17-6:0.8.17-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 25 2015 00:39:58 with gcc 4.6.3
The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
in a future release. **It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv**
(see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, image2, from '01-20150528100343-00.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1024x576, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: That's not `ffmpeg`, but a dead counterfeit from a fork.